Triangles and circles
How can I generalize this problem?
That is, how to express $R$ as a function of $R_1,R_2,R_3$ in this triangle:

The linked problem describes the special case that the outer triangle is equilateral, and there is an interesting solution in that case. This generalization seems of equal interest, and hopefully there is also a nice solution.
I applied the Pythagorean Theorem several times but I couldn't isolate $R$.
Can someone please help me?

Start from any triangle $T$ with vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3$. Extend indexing of vertices by periodicity. i.e. for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{1,2,3\}$, let $v_k = v_{\text{mod}(k-1,3)+1}$.
Let $R$ be the inradius of $T$. For each $k \in \{1,2,3\}$, let

$\theta_k = \frac12 \angle (v_{k-1}v_k v_{k+1} )$ be the half-angle of triangle $T$ at vertex $v_k$.
$R_k$ be the radius of the circle tangent to the side $v_{k-1} v_k$, the side $v_k v_{k+1}$ and the incircle.

It is not hard to show $\frac{R_k}{R} = \frac{1-\sin\theta_k}{1 + \sin\theta_k}$.
This leads to
$$\sin\theta_k = \frac{R - R_k}{R + R_k}
\quad\implies\quad \tan\theta_k =\frac{R-R_k}{\sqrt{4RR_k}}$$
Since $\theta_1 + \theta_2 + \theta_3 = \frac{\pi}{2}$,  $\tan\theta_k$ satisfy
a trigonometric identity:
$$1 = \tan\theta_1 \tan\theta_2 + \tan\theta_2 \tan\theta_3 + \tan\theta_3 \tan\theta_1$$
In terms of $R$ and $R_k$, we find $R$ is a root of a quadratic polynomial:
$$4R = \frac{(R-R_1)(R-R_2)}{\sqrt{R_1R_2}}
+  \frac{(R-R_2)(R-R_3)}{\sqrt{R_2R_3}} + \frac{(R-R_3)(R-R_1)}{\sqrt{R_3R_1}}\tag{*1}$$
As a double check, consider the case where $R_1 = R_2 = R_3 = 4$, above equations reduces to
$$4R = \frac34(R-4)^2\quad\iff\quad (R-12)(3R-4) = 0$$ 
Since we know $R > R_1,R_2,R_3$, we find $R = 12$ for this particular case. Reproducing the number embedded in answers of your linked question.
Update
As pointed out by @Blue in comment, if one set $s_k = \sqrt{R_k}$, one can factorize $(*1)$ as
$$(R - s_1s_2 - s_2s_3 - s_3s_1)(R(s_1 + s_2 + s_3) - s_1s_2s_3) = 0$$
This implies $R = s_1s_2 + s_2s_3 + s_3s_1$ or $\frac{s_1 s_2 s_3}{s_1+s_2+s_3}$. Since $R > R_1, R_2, R_3$, we can rule out the 
second possibility. The end result is a more compact formula for $R$:
$$R = \sqrt{R_1R_2} + \sqrt{R_2R_3} + \sqrt{R_3R_1}$$

Interestingly, if we solve your quadratic for $R$ (which I'll write as $r$), we get $$r = s_1 s_2+s_2 s_3+s_3 s_1 \quad\text{and}\quad r = \frac{s_1 s_2 s_3}{s_1+s_2+s_3}$$
where $s_k:=\sqrt{r_k}$. These seem to invite rewriting as
$$r^\pm = s_1^\pm s_2^\pm s_3^\pm\left(s_1^\mp+s_2^\mp+s_3^\mp\right)$$
where $x^{\pm}$ is shorthand for $x^{\pm 1}$.

@Blue, interesting...
